# Query Sum of Nested Array-Length COSMOS DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Assume this model:

Having a collection of `Writers` documents, each `Writer` has some `Posts`. and each `Post` contains an array of `Comments`.

JSON:

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "partitionKey": "somePK",
 "name": "John",
 "posts": [
     {
         "id": "20",
         "title": "post1",
         "comments": [
             {
                 "body": "some body"
             }
         ]
     },
     {
         "id": "21",
         "title": "post2",
         "comments": [
             {
                 "body": "some new body"
             }
         ]
     }
 ]
}
```

I need a query that returns the following output:

```
[
 {
     "WriterName": "John",
     "WriterCommentsCount": 2
 }
]
```

I managed to get the writer's comment but I have a problem getting the name(or other properties) beside the `WriterCommentsCount`. Any idea of how to get the writer's name?

this is what I've tried so far (only the writer's comments count)
[image]

Comment: SELECT c.name,sum(array_length(post.comments)) as countC  FROM c join post in c.posts where c.id = '1' group by c.name

Comment: But I don't think my answer is better than the answer posted below.

Answer (score 2):

Along your thought, if we execute sql

```
SELECT c.name,array_length(post.comments) as countC FROM c join post in c.posts where c.id = '1'
```

we'll get  response like below:

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "countC": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "countC": 3
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "countC": 0
    }
]
```

So using this `SELECT c.name,sum(array_length(post.comments)) as countC FROM c join post in c.posts where c.id = '1'` will return error 'Property reference 'c.name' is invalid'. The solution is using '**group by c.name**'.

My answer in the comment and the one from @404 are all the same in this point, the difference is that I followed your thought using sum function and he uses count(1) after expand all the child item. My sql costs '3.09 RUs' and his costs the same on my test data.

Here's the situation screenshot.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is making a flat structure where you have an entry for each comment. After that you can use `GROUP BY` to group all entries for the same name. Try the following:

```
SELECT 
    c.name AS WriterName, 
    COUNT(1) AS WriterCommentsCount
FROM c
JOIN s IN c.posts
JOIN t IN s.comments
WHERE c.id = '1'
GROUP BY c.name
```